# Extract value of template parameter from an alias template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, rtti

I am making an alias template of Eigen's Matrix class and I was wondering if it was possible to extract the value from one of the "unused" template parameters.

```
enum MatrixType{
    FOO,
    BAR
};
template<int ROWS, int COLS, MatrixType FOO>
using Matrix = Eigen::Matrix<double, ROWS, COLS>
```

I want to be able to extract the MatrixType value at a later point (specifically within the MatrixBase plugin but unrelated). I've seen the approaches on this site such as:

```
template<template <MatrixType> typename T, MatrixType N>
constexpr MatrixType extract(const T<N>&) { return N; }
```

But I haven't been able to quite line it up with my specific situation. Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Just like `typedef` doesn't introduce a new type, template alias doesn't introduce a new template. `YourTemplate<Matrix<1, 2, FOO>>` is indistinguishable from `YourTemplate<Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 2>>` - it's impossible to make the latter behave differently than the former.

Comment: You could have a workaround if you have a wrapper struct that contains the matrix type and the eigen matrix. So you write your code in such a way that it take the wrapper instead of the eigen matrix. This way you can basically access the enum type when its neccessary.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ok thats what I was afraid of

Comment: @M.Mac  I was hoping not to go that route (wrapper around Eigen) but it seems like it may be the only way. thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution that (unfortunately) doesn't involve an alias template could look like the following code [link](https://onlinegdb.com/Hk_3v7MwI):

```
struct Eigen{
    //struct that simulates Eigen
    template<typename T, auto ROWS, auto COLS>
    struct Matrix{};
};

enum MatrixType{FOO, BAR};

template<int ROWS, int COLS, MatrixType enum_para>
struct Matrix{
    static constexpr MatrixType enum_type = enum_para;
    using eigen_matrix_t = Eigen::Matrix<double, ROWS, COLS>;
};


template<auto rows, auto cols, MatrixType enum_para>
constexpr auto myFunction(Matrix<rows, cols, enum_para> myObject){

    return 0;

}

int main()
{
    Matrix<2,2,FOO> my_matrix; //declare struct

    decltype(my_matrix)::eigen_matrix_t matrix_a; //access eigen
    auto my_enum_a = decltype(my_matrix)::enum_type; //access matrixType enum

    Matrix<2,2,FOO>::eigen_matrix_t matrix_b;
    auto my_enum_b = Matrix<2,2,FOO>::enum_type;

    auto result = myFunction(my_matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like it's the best approach, I was really hoping there would be a way to bury that Matrixtype state within Eigen but I don't know if that is possible...